# Capture packets coming to router

Tags: wireshark, router

How can I use wireshark to capture all the packets destined to the router. I want to run wireshark on the router. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to run `wireshark` on the router. 
What you can do, however, is run `wireshark` on one of the computers in the network in sniffer/monitor mode and filter out all the packets with destination address set to address of the router. Note, if you want to capture also the wired packets to your router, this won't work.